# Why won't MS Office start?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

When I open MS Office two dialog boxes appear:

> The command cannot be performed because a dialog box is open. Click
>   OK, and then close open dialog boxes to continue.

then

> Microsoft Office Word has not been installed for the current user.
>   Please run setup to install the application.

Can someone tell me why this happened?

Comment: Is this a new install? Has there been recent updates/upgrades done to the PC? Have you tried to uninstall and reinstall Office?

Comment: No, it's old installation. I didn't do any changes to my PC. And I haven't tried to reinstall, I was hoping that I don't have to reinstall! :)

Comment: I would just reinstall it considering it would take 20 minutes at most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/fix-microsoft-office-word-has-not-been-installed-for-the-current-user-error/) will help you!!
  It happened because apparently you have pirated version of MS Office. This link describes how to fix this problem. Just copy old MSO.DLL file to `{Drive}\Files\Pfiles\Common\MSShared\Office11\` and the problem will be solved. Renstalling or repairing MS Office won't help here.

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't have a lot of detail to it, so this is a general answer.

I would suggest repairing the installation from the `Control Panel > Add/Remove Programs`. Choose to repair rather than remove. If that doesn't work, check the article below.

This can be caused by the user not having proper permissions to complete the installation, a third party program restricting the use or complete installation, or the user not having enough permission to use the types of files associated with the program.

Here is a MS Support article related to this - [You receive an error message when you install an Office program or open an Office program or document](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/838687)